# start node.js app after all services are started

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, amqp

for example i have two services: db and queue
I need to start server after db and amqp connects to their servers.

for now i have something like this *server.js*:

```
let mongo = require('./server/db');
let qManager = require('./server/amqp');

mongo.connect(()=>{
    qManager.connect(()=>{
        http.listen(3001, function () {
            console.log('listening on *:3001');
        });
    });
});
```

mongo connection method:

```
const connectDb = (callback) => {
    if (state.db) return state.db;
    let connection = MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, (err, db) => {
        if (err) {
            connectDb();
        }
        state.db = db;
        console.log('Mongo connected.');
        callback();
    });
};
```

rabbitmq connection method:

```
const connect = (callback) => {
    connection = amqp.connect(url)
        .then(conn => {
            module.connection = conn;
            channel = conn.createChannel();
            console.log('Queue connected.');
            pythonResultListener();

            callback()
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error('Connect failed: %s', err);
        });
    return connection;
};
```

maybe there is much better way? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several approaches to handle asynchronous flow.
For your particular case:

- [async.waterfall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-waterfall)
- promises approach
- generators/coroutines
- async/await

Very quick example with `async/await`:

```
// First you modify your callback function to be promises
// For example mongoconnect method implementation:
const connectDb = function() {
  return new Promise (resolve, reject) => {
    if (state.db) return state.db;
    let connection = MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, (err, db) => {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      state.db = db;
      console.log('Mongo connected.');
      resolve();
    });
  });
};
```

And now, assuming you have promises A, B, C, your goal is to call them one by one:

```
const promises = [ A, B, C ];
for (const promiseFunc of promises) {
  const res = await promiseFunc();
  // For cases you need to return something
  console.log(res);
}
```

More info you can find [here](http://thecodebarbarian.com/common-async-await-design-patterns-in-node.js.html).